# Batch Script + Multiple variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently trying to write my first batch script ever.

What it does:

- it gets all files from a certain folder and puts each of it in a rar
- it generates an URL shortcut for the desktop

So far everything works fine, but here is the problem: I would like to create the shortcuts with unique URLs. Right now I am simply passing the URL via the script like this:

```
script.bat http://example.com
```

And the script does the following:

```
SET LINK        =%1

::For each file that is in the dir "Ori"
FOR %%i IN (%BASEPATH%\Ori\*.*) DO (

    echo [InternetShortcut] > "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    echo URL=%LINK% >> "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    echo IconFile=%LINK%/favicon.ico >> "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    echo IconIndex=0 >> "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"

)
```

Of course this way, all Shortcuts will lead to `http://example.com`.

I would like to be able to define an unique URL for each shortcut that is being created.

Since I am a total beginner, I dont really know where to start... and was hoping for a suggestion!

P.S. Just to give you an idea what I would need, but this doesnt work:

```
script.bat {http://example.com,http://example1.com,http://example2.com}
```

And than the script should use URL 1 for the first shortcut, URL 2 for the second and so on.

**Update:**

It works fine now following jeb´s answer below. However, I was wondering: would it be possible to do the same job again with another variable? So that it looks kinda like this:

```
script.bat http://example.com http://example1.com http://example2.com NewVar1 NewVar2 NewVar3
```

And the NewVar should be saved just like:

```
SET NEWVAR=%2
```

How could I make the script know when the URL variables are done and the NewVar variables start?

And than be called like

```
!NEWVAR!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid spaces when using `SET` else you create variable names with spaces!

You can enumerate all parameters with the SHIFT command.

Then you can use something like

```
script.bat http://example.com http://example1.com http://example2.com

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET LINK=%1

::For each file that is in the dir "Ori"
FOR %%i IN (%BASEPATH%\Ori\*.*) DO (

    echo [InternetShortcut] > "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    echo URL=!LINK! >> "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    echo IconFile=!LINK!/favicon.ico >> "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    echo IconIndex=0 >> "%BASEPATH%\New\%%~ni.URL"
    shift
    call set link=%%1

)
```

The `SHIFT` will move all parameters, so the next time you access %1 you get the next parameter.
But as you are in a block you can't access the *current* %1 directly, so I use the `CALL %%` trick here.

And to access the current value of `LINK` in the block I used the delayed expansion (`!Link!`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works as expected now :) However, I was wondering if you might could even take a look at my updated question too?

Comment: »avoid« is too soft a word, I guess ;-)